# Passing a 2D Array to function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I tried passing a 2D array to a function in C++ and I didn`t understand something:

```
//My array declaration:
int array[5][5]={{....}}; //I declared and filled the array with values
//My different function tries:
void passArr(int **array) //ERROR
void passArr(int *array[5]) //ERROR
void passArr(int *(*array)) //ERROR
void passArr(int (*(*array))) //ERROR
void passArr(int (*array)[5]) //WORKS
```

All errors were: `[Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[5]' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void passArr(int**)'`

Why do the errors show up and most importantly what is the difference between `int *array[5]` and `int (*array)[5]` when passing as an argument?

If `int (*array)[5]` worked, then why didn´t `int *(*array)` or `int (*(*array)))` also work?

Comment: One workaround around C++ type system would be to use a structure instead: `struct array5x5 { int data[5][5]; }; void passArr(array5x5 *array) { ... }`. Othewise, use C++ types like std::array, std::vector... You could also pass a reference to your array with something like `int (&array)[5][5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just different things. Reading from right to left might be helpful.

```
int array[5][5]  -> array of array of int, could decay to pointer to array of int
int (*array)[5]  -> pointer to array of int, could be converted from the above

int **array      -> pointer to pointer to int
int *(*array)    -> same as above
int (*(*array))  -> same as above

int *array[5]    -> array of pointer to int
```

Comment: It's also important to know that C/C++ sometimes acts like a pointer to x is the same as an array of x but sometimes does not, e.g. in `struct X {int *x; int y[20]}` or `sizeof z`.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, a 2D array is an *Array-of-Arrays*. The first element of a 2D array is the first 1D array it contains. The conversion is specified in [C++ Standard - Array-to-pointer Conversion [conv.array]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array)

When you declared a *plain-old* 2D array as:

```
int array[5][5]
```

You have an array of `int[5]` arrays. As with any array, it is converted to a pointer to its first element on access. The first element being an array of `int[5]`, so the resulting type is:

```
int (*)[5]
```

A *pointer-to-array-of* `int[5]`. So for your 2D array named `array`, that is:

```
int (*array)[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in the ***"C++"*** language, it is strongly advisable to use one of the very-many *"container classes"* for this purpose. Or perhaps a `class` of your own devising.

"A simple pointer" has no way to convey that it is pointing to "a 2D array," nor what its dimensions are.  The extent of its job-description is that it knows how to point to "a bunch of bytes, or nothing."

But if instead you provided your caller with a reference to a *class,* your caller could now "ask the class" for what it needed, "and the class would magically know."  Just hand the class `(X,Y)` and you either get the right answer or a runtime exception is thrown.  Every single time ... and by the way, *efficiently.*

This is a **much** more-robust way to write code, and it really is the reason why the C++ language was invented.

Answer (score 0):

Versions 1,3, and 4 are all the same. Version 2 is also the same as 1,3, and 4, because when passing an array to a function the array decays to a pointer.

Version 2 can also be written

```
void passArr(int* array[5])
```

Which probably shows the association of the asterisk with the type more clearly: it is an array of five int-pointers. With the array decaying to a pointer, it becomes

```
void passArr(int** array)
```

All of them mean that the entry of the array are addresses, pointing to another array:

```
 [ * | * | * | * | * ]
   |    |    |    |   +-> [,,,,]
   |    |    |    +-> [,,,,]
And so on.
```

What you have is an array when each entry is an array of 5 ints, not a pointer to one (arrays bear a lot of resemblance with pointers, but they aren't pointers!)

Your matrix looks like this:

```
[ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,,,,], [,,,,], [,,,,], [,,,,] ]
```

So, array is a pointer to an int[5], not a pointer to pointer to int. And that is what the parentheses do in version 5: int (*array)[5]. This binds the asterisk closer to array.